# For some reason, my D3 Map is displaying upside down - how can I flip it?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, topojson

Have a topoJSON file that I am importing - seems like this should be easy to flip, but I have no idea. Should I be transforming the object after it's created or  adjusting the JSON? I tried using some projections, which flipped the object, but distorted it all over the place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.counties {
  fill: blue;
}

.states {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>


var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var path = d3.geoPath()

 //first make projection  
  //var projection = d3.geoMercator();
  //var path = d3.geoPath()
  //  .projection(projection);



d3.json("data.topojson", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;


 var counties = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties),
                    counties = counties.features.filter(function(d) { return d.properties.AWATER === 0; });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(counties)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", 'blue')
      .append('g')
      attr('transform', 'rotate(180 0 0)');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't using a projection - so the coordinates in the file are translated to pixels with no transformation. If your data has typical geographic coordinates, or lat longs that are both positive, high values are at the north end (the top in most maps), and low values are at the south end (the bottom in most maps).

In svg coordinates, low values are located at the top and increase as one moves towards the bottom - the opposite of most geographic coordinate conventions. You could use a geoIdentity as your projection to flip the json's y coordinates:

```
var projection = d3.geoIdentity()
  .reflectY(true)
  .fitSize([width,height],geojson)
```

Where geojson is your feature collection: `topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties)`

And then use it with your path:

```
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but for some reason the page isn't showing anything and throwing no errors. Could there be something with scale/placement I'm missing? Edit: It seems like the .reflectY(true) is causing me to lose the map.

Comment: My bad, you will need to modify the translate with this. FitSize will allow centering for this. No errors and no features means features are drawn out of view generally. I've updated the answer.