# Topojson map upside down after upgrading d3 to v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have created a simple extension of the zipcode map using a topojson file and d3 seen [here](https://gist.github.com/jefffriesen/6892860#file-zips_us_topo-json)

My working version can be seen [here](https://bl.ocks.org/choskey/8e551b36eb0aa919804ede559d73b53a)

I am trying to update it to use v5 of d3js and no matter what I do the map ends up upside down.  See my non-working version here below and [here](https://bl.ocks.org/choskey/49a767c84e80cc321284baaebfb97077):

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

I see other answers here on stackoverflow but they all seem to relate to creating the topojson file.  I am using the same topojson file in both solutions, but one is upside down and the other isn't.

```
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://agiledragonconsulting.com/js/svg-pan-zoom.js"></script>
<div id="button">
     <a href="#" onclick="changeColor(); return false;">Change    color</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="getZipZoom(); return false;">Get zoom</a>
</div>
    <script>
    var buttonheightceil = Math.ceil(document.getElementById("button").getBoundingClientRect().height);

    var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth - 8;
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - buttonheightceil - 20;
    console.log("width = "+width+", height = "+height);
    var path = d3.geoPath();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("id","map")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var promises = d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jefffriesen/6892860/raw/e1f82336dde8de0539a7bac7b8bc60a23d0ad788/zips_us_topo.json");

    console.log("before promises");

    promises.then(ready);

    function ready(us) {
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "counties")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.zip_codes_for_the_usa).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "zip")
            .attr("id", function(d) {return d.properties.zip; })
            .attr("data-zip", function(d) {return d.properties.zip; })
            .attr("data-state", function(d) {return d.properties.state; })
            .attr("data-name", function(d) {return d.properties.name; })
            .attr("stroke","#383838")
            .attr("stroke-width",".1px")
            .attr("fill","none")
            .attr("d", path)

        var panZoom = svgPanZoom('#map', {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            controlIconsEnabled: true,
            minZoom: 0.1,
            maxZoom: 100,
            fit: true,
            contain: true,
            center: true
        });
    }
    function getZipZoom() {
        var panZoom = svgPanZoom('#map');
        var thisZoom = panZoom.getZoom();
        console.log("");
        console.log(thisZoom);
    }
    function changeColor() {
        var thisZip = "00014";
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("zip");
        console.log("");
        console.log("setting color.  x.length = "+x.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if(x[i].getAttribute("id")===thisZip){
                x[i].setAttribute("stroke","#ff0000");
                x[i].parentElement.appendChild(x[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect to see an right-side up map of the US, like this [one](https://bl.ocks.org/choskey/8e551b36eb0aa919804ede559d73b53a)

Comment: Latitudes increase in value as one moves up, but in SVG, y values increase in value as one moves down. As you don't use a projection, values are translated as pixel values, resulting in an upside down image. You can use a geoIdentity to flip the y values (as seen in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716349/7106086), or this [updated block](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/d3dd607846694bce56ddfa573f516cf4).

Comment: As an aside, once flipped you should probably use a projection: you are essentially projecting as a Plate Carree, which looks a bit odd, try `d3.geoAlbers()` as seen [here](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/6146a82b4468b39fb099c7db8de133c4). Also, as a general comment, Both geoIdentity and a geoProjection allow for [fitSize](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projection_fitSize) and [fitExtent](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projection_fitExtent) methods which could simplify your zooming and centering process (which relies on svg-pan-zoom to center everything initially) - and help with stroke widths.

Comment: Why would the same topojson file be upside down using v5 of d3 but it's right-side up using v3 of d3?  I didn't use a projection earlier, or flip it, so I'm unclear on why that has to be done now.  It's the same exact json.

Comment: OH, and thank you so much for the updated block!  And I do intend to replace svg-pan-zoom with all d3, which is part of why I needed to update it to use the latest d3.  I was just trying to keep everything else the same in order to make the central difficulty more clear.

Comment: Hope this helps, feel free to ask for clarifications if I'm unclear at all.

Comment: As for v3, the default projection was an AlbersUsa projection of a geoPath, so this would work out for projecting data right way up without expressly specifying a projection.